# Редактирование записей ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-studio, adapter, expandablelistview

Всем привет! Чтобы изменять данные группы в ExpandbleListView, менять надо сам объект группы или View, лежащий в ее основе? И если последнее,то как можно его получить в методе gerChildView адаптера? Я так понимаю нужно элемент ViewGroup parent задействовать? Всем заранее спасибо за ответы и участие.